# is angular's digest cycle asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following piece of code:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.$emit("connectionadd.flowchart", data);
});

if (data.cancel) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

I'm wondering whether the execution can reach `if (data.cancel)` line before everything inside `$scope.$apply` callback is executed? If `$digest` is async, than it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not, pseudo code:

```
function $apply(expr) {
  try {
    return $eval(expr);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  } finally {
    $root.$digest();
  }
}
```

So the answer is that it will not reach `if (data.cancel)` before completing, although it is possible to make that happen with `$scope.$applyAsyncc`

$digest is also not async, but even it was purely by answering your question, then callback still would be executed before, because digest is called after the callback execution.

You can review $digest code here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js